# Composite list item in Android

Tags: android, listview

In my chat app I have composite types of messages. It can be only text, can be a mix of text and images and videos. What is the best way to use android layout to show such composite items in ListView.
Currently I draw these messages programmatically. But this cause a lot of problem when it comes to different screens adjustment.
Ideally I want to have xml layout for each(text, image, video) and then add them in adapter according the type.

Sample of messages:

```
text
image
image

image
video 
image
text

text
image
text
image
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. You have to create different layouts for content. In your adapter you have to inflate these layouts according to view you want to draw.

Eg. Adapter.java

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        if(position % 2== 0) { // your condition
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_text_msg, null);
        } else {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_image_msg, null);
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

You are ready.

Comment: can I use layoutInflater to dynamically compose my row item? So instead of preparing all variations of message layouts(image_text_image layout, text_image layout), I would just insert appropriate element with its own layout(layout for text, layout for image, etc).

Comment: You can use layout inflater dynamically. I did not understand last part of your comment.

Comment: what I mean: I will have empty list item layout, which I will populate on run with other small layouts basing on type of content(text, image, video). So I wouldn't have to prepare all variations of layout, but build layout on run.